# Пунктуация при обороте с "как"

Tags: пунктуация, как, приложение

"Сегодня у нас во дворце праздник, а вам, как главным гостям торжества, нельзя не присутствовать."  Здесь будет обособление? И почему?

Answer (score 3):

Сегодня у нас во дворце праздник, а вам, **как главным гостям торжества**, нельзя не присутствовать.

Это не сравнительный оборот, а оборот со значением тождества (вы ― это главные гости). Такие конструкции также рассматриваются в теме "обособленные приложения".

В этом случае **следует различать значение причины и  значение "в качестве".** Очевидно, что в данном случае это не значение "в качестве", а значение причины: так как вы являетесь главными гостями.

Сравнить: Сегодня у нас во дворце праздник, и вы приглашены  **как главные гости торжества**. Здесь значение "в качестве."

Comment: А можно еще один вопрос? "Она заныла как ребенок". Здесь "как" же входит в грамматическую основу? " Она была ребенком". Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @Екатерина Лучше (и для Вас тоже), если бы Вы оформили это отдельным вопросом.